# What does iOS6.1 | iOS6.1 SDK exactly mean in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode5

I recently update my Xcode 4.6.3 to Xcode 5,then I download 5.1 and 6.1 simulator in preference panel, but when I selected simulator to run my project, I saw items like (iOS6.1|iOS6.1 SDK) (iOS7|iOS7.0) ,etc. But we can only see item iOS6.1/iOS5.1,without (iOS6 SDK) in Xcode 4.6.3.

When I select (iOS 5.1| iOS 5.1 SDK) or (iOS 5.1 | iOS 6.1 SDK), my project run normally and has no difference.

So, my question is what items like (iOS6.1 | iOS6.1 SDK) exactly mean in Xcode 5? I know what (iOS6.1) mean, but DO NOT know what (iOS6.1 SDK) mean.

Comment: where exactly do you see these options? I checked deployment targets, schemes, build settings and even within the simulator menu and everywhere there's only mention of "iOS x.x" or just "x.x" without the SDK. SDK = Software Development Kit, the software you're using to develop for this OS version.

Comment: thanks for your kindly answer. My reputation is not enough to give you a screenshot. I know what SDK is, what confused me is that why a simulator could choose two different base sdks to run.

Comment: Simulator can run a multitude of iOS versions in order for you to specifically build & test your code with a certain iOS version. For example if you take alternative code paths depending on whether the user has iOS 5, 6 or 7 installed you need some way to test that the code paths are properly executing for each iOS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 6.1 SDK is the framework used to run an iOS simulator. Every Xcode version comes with an upgraded simulator which you can use for testing. Please prefer to this link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_SDK[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_SDK)

This will help you to understand. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I got the idea that a simulator run iOS6.1 SDK is called iOS6.1 simulator, a simulator run iOS5.1 SDK is called iOS5.1 simulator, just like our iPhone. But Why a iOS5.1 simulator can use both iOS6.1 SDK and iOS5.1 SDK?